# How to Set a Fallback Value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple webpage that returns nutrition info for ingredients searched. The data itself is retrieved from an API then pushed into their respective empty arrays (carbs, calories, sodium, etc.) The problem is this API does not return the same array for every single ingredient. For example, it doesn't return fiber for 1 cup of rice. I'm getting errors because the fiber doesn't exist for this ingredient. I'm using react. How can I set a fallback value to make sure I don't get an error in this scenario? I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
dietaryFiber = {(totalFiber === undefined) ? 0 : totalFiber}
```

Edit:

Ok, I think the problem occurs actually in the loop, where searchArray is the input value [[1, cup, rice], [1, whole, apple pie]] for example, and dataArray is the response from this API. It's giving me an error because FIBTG (fiber) doesn't exist when I try to search for rice. What can I do to get around it? Sorry for the ambiguity.

```
const fiber = []

for(var i=0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
   fiber.push(dataArray[i].totalNutrients.FIBTG.quantity)
}
```

Comment: You can try `dietaryFiber = {totalFiber ? 0 : totalFiber}`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just updated the question. Can you please take a look? I think the error occurs in the loop.

Comment: what is `searchArray`?

Comment: searchArray is the input value [[1, cup, rice], [1, whole, apple pie]] for example. I number of searchArrays returns i number of dataArray, that is the idea.

Comment: Ut is an array of array. So why you use `dataArray[i].totalNutrients`? What is `totalNutrients`?

Comment: What is totalNutrients and FIBTG?

Comment: Rajdeep Debnath's answer below solved my problem. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either **Nullish Coalescing** Operator or **Ternary** operator.

In **Ternary** operator `totalFiber` values like `null`, `undefined`, `0` will be treated as falsy value

```
dietaryFiber = totalFiber ? 0 : totalFiber
```

In **Nullish Coalescing** operator `totalFiber` values like `null`, `undefined` will be treated as falsy value, `0` will not be treated as falsy value

```
dietaryFiber = totalFiber ?? 0
```

You can also use **Optional chaining** javascript operator to check if any property is undefined and gracefully return undefined without throwing error

```
dataArray[i].totalNutrients.FIBTG?.quantity ?? 0
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just updated the question. Can you please take a look? I think the error occurs in the loop.

Comment: Where are you searching for `rice`? I don't see the code. But I updated my code to account if FIBTG is undefined

Comment: You sir are a wizard. I did not know such thing (optional chaining) exists. Clearly I have much to learn. Thank you and I will remember it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think:

> dietaryFiber = {totalFiber ? 0 : totalFiber}

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just updated the question. Can you please take a look? I think the error occurs in the loop.